# julia: `using` module with listed functions does not define the module itself

Tags: julia

```
julia> using Random: rand; Random
ERROR: UndefVarError: Random not defined
julia> using Random; Random
Random
```

Is this working as intended? I have a dirty workaround: `using Random: Random, rand`. But that is quite ugly. Does there exist a better one?

Comment: `using Random: rand` just imports the name `:rand` from `Random` while `import Random: rand` imports the module `:Random` and the name `:rand` from that module into `Main`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for:

```
import Random
```